# After Click on button record update in one2many field and also in model

Tags: javascript, odoo

In my form view, there is one one2many field, that contain Question field with many2many_tags. After click on any of the question tags, it is displayed in edit mode in fields available in the form view. I have also one button. After doing some changes into the field and then click on the update question button I want to make changes in the model as well as it should be updated in many2many_tags of one2many field.

I hope, I have given detail information and for a detailed understanding attached screenshot.

[image]

Any help or any other way is also appreciated

Comment: So basically when you edit the question the old name of the question in many2many_tag stay the same .

Comment: Not the same it should be replaced at many2mamy_tags as well as in the database also. In short questions, record should be updated.

Comment: Do you have a Many2one field in your model to question model, because in order to know witch question was clicked you need to keep the ID of the record. So my question to you when you click on the many2many_tags do you save the selected record in some many2one in the parent model or just you save the name and the type of question

Comment: No, I don’t have many2one field in my model to question. But in my model one2many field to page model and on page one2many field to question. The question model contain many2one field to the page. With this relation, I have created a question record and also save.

Comment: Click on many2many_tags I am able to get ID Of question. I am able to get the ID, calling the python method from javascript. After getting the ID of question I am not able to use this ID. Because I have used another button to update question. On this button, I am trying to call the python method to update the question. But didn’t the question is never updated.

Comment: But how will you know witch tag was clicked you need to have Many2one field in your model so when you click on the button just update that Many2one field and the changes will be shown on the one2many too, I hope you understood the idea

Comment: No, I didn't understand the idea.

Comment: You need to have a Many2one to save the selected record then when you click on update question you should update the same record using the model fields.

Comment: after using many2one field. I am not able to create relation as survey -> Pages -> Questions. because for survey, pages, and questions different module is used. I want to achieve this as after clicking on tag able access ID of click tag and this ID is sent to update button, then update question click on update button.